# Injection of a quotient map under restriction.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ be a vector subspace of $V$. Let $A$ be a basis of $W$. Since we know that any basis of a subspace can be extended to the basis of the entire vector space, so there exists basis $B$ of $V$ such that $A$ is a subset of $B$. Let $f:V→V/W$ be a quotient map. Then show that the map $f|_{B \backslash A}:B \backslash A→V/W$ is injective and it's image is a basis of $V/W$.

How can I show that without using any tough calculation. Please suggest me any answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $f$ sends the element $x\in V$ to the coset $x+W\in V/W$.

To show that $f|_{B\setminus A}$ is injective, assume that $f(b_1)=f(b_2)$ with $b_1,\,b_2\in B\setminus A$ and $b_1\ne b_2$.

We have:

$$\begin{align*}
b_1+W &= b_2+W\\
b_1 - b_2 &\in W\\
b_1 - b_2 &= \sum \alpha_i a_i
\end{align*}
$$
with $a_i \in A$. This gives you a non-trivial linear relation between elements of $B$, and this contradicts the fact that $B$ is a basis.

Now, each element of $V/W$ is of the form $x+W$ for some $x\in V$, since $f$ is surjective. If we write $x = \sum \alpha_i a_i + \sum\beta_j b_j$; with $a_i\in A$ and $b_j\in B\setminus A$, we have:

$$\begin{align*}
x+W &= (\sum \alpha_i a_i + \sum\beta_j b_j)+W\\
 &= \sum(\alpha_i a_i+W) + \sum(\beta_j b_j+W)\\
 &= \sum \beta_j f(b_j)
\end{align*}
$$

because, as $a_i\in W$, $\alpha_i a_i+W = 0$ in $V/W$. This shows that the $f(b_j)$ constitute a spanning set of $V/W$.